# How to move the text throughout screen using RenderTransform(rotation transform) in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Here is my code , i am using rotation transform and i am getting text rotating in 360 degree 
but i want it to move over all the screen with constant speed.
any one can help in this please?

```
void OnCompositionTargetRendering(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Time-based
    TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    rotate.Angle = (elapsedTime.TotalMinutes * 360) % 360;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CompositeTransform, where you can specify both rotation and translation

Answer (score 0):

```
//use layout transform not rendertransform

//for example
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="200" Height="20" LayoutTransform="{StaticResource Rotate}">
```